# Filtering features only in layout

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Is it possible to only show one certain point of a layer in the print composer, but have them all shown in the QGis main window?

For an inventory of buildings, I want to have an overview of all buildings on the map in the main window, but in the layout, I want the atlas to only show one building at a time, so that there can't be any confusion about which building is being described.

I know how to insert a rule to only show one certain point ($id =  @atlas_featureid), which is great for the actual layout output. However, with this rule, I also only see one point in the main window and only have access to the other ones through the attribute tabel, instead of just being able to click on them (plus: I completely lose overview of the amount of points). At this moment, I just delete the rule as long as I'm working in the main window and not printing anything and then adding it, when I want to print my atlas. But this is of course a bit laborious, as we have to print the layout in different phases of the project and I have to add and delete that rule several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your layout set up as you want it, you can tick the `lock layer` and `lock layer style` box in the map properties. Now, when you go back to the main map you can change the style of the layer or switch to a duplicate layer with another style with out changing the look of the output map.